# Make a different connection center for the same express-ws function

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, express-ws

first of all I want to apologize if my English is not perfect and if the title does not explain my situation very well.

I will summarize:

I created a code allowing to make different chat between several people using `express-ws`.
I decided to make a chat system with several IDs and I came to this conclusion:

```js
let connects = [];
app.ws('/chat/:id', (ws, req) => {
    app.get('/hello/:id', (req, res) => {
        //...
    })
    connects.push(ws);


    ws.on('message', message => {
      console.log('Received a message: ', message);      
    });
    
    ws.on('close', () => {
      console.log('A user disconnected');
      connects = connects.filter(conn => {
        return (conn === ws) ? false : true;
      });
    });
})
```

The problem is that `connects` supports all clients and I would like it to only support clients from req.params.id

Regards,

Stan

Comment: You would have to use a middleware that checks if ```req.params.id``` exist if you need help with it tag me let me drop a sample code

Comment: Ok, can you drop the code please?